# python 3 sorting a list of tuples by the highest number

Tags: python, list, sorting

How can I sort this:

```
 [('Pineapple', 1), ('Apple', 2), ('Banana', 1)]
```

into this:

```
['Apple','Pineapple','Banana']
```

I mean to sort it in ordered the the highest number will be at left of the new list(if they have the same number its doesn't really matter).
I tried using this:

```
sorted(fruitlist, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

but it still doesn't go as I wish

Comment: `sorted(fruitlist, key=lambda x: x[1])` ? `x[0]` would still sort by the first tuple element, i.e. the string

Comment: And then to get the highest number first, use `sorted(fruitlist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want descending numerical order, you can sort by the negative of the number:

```
sorted(fruitlist, key=lambda x: -x[1])  # x[1] is the number 
                                        # (x[0] is the string)
```

For that and other data types, you could use the reverse=True parameter of the sorted function.